# What did Lorraine see that caused her to lock herself in a room for 8 days?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-conjuring-universe, the-conjuring

I know it's a bit late, but just watched *The Conjuring* yesterday, and I'm very curious to understand one thing:

There is a portion where Ed Warren describes some past incident to Roger Perron (while repairing an old car of Roger's) that Lorraine Warren had **seen something** when they were performing the exorcism on a demon, and she locked herself in a room for eight days afterward. **What had Lorraine seen that made her lock herself in a room for that long?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visions showing **death of Ed Warren** led Lorraine to lock herself for 8 days.

Source [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130721204854AAbYu8S):

> Ed said in the film, every time they're involved in an exorcism or other deep paranormal investigations, "**it takes something out of her, little by little**." They had probably just finished an investigation, and she was in recovery mode. If you read up on interviews with Ed and Lorraine Warren, there are actually many articles where she talks about having to seclude herself from her family (ex: lock herself in her room) for days at a time before she can begin to recover from her experiences.

Comment: how could you be sure that it was the death of Ed ??

Comment: In conjuring 2 when lorraine tells Ed that in the visions she saw his death then Ed asks her the question was this the reason for locking yourself and she nods her head.

Comment: i haven't watched part-2 yet.. :P